# Which statistical test is more suitable?

Tags: self-study, chi-squared-test, z-test, two-sample

In an exam question I was asked to consider the following data related to education loan taken or not for pursuing higher education and formulate a suitable hypothesis and validate it by using an appropriate statistical procedure.

| Education Loan | Boys | Girls |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Loan Taken | 300 | 100 |
| Not Taken | 150 | 250 |

The most obvious hypothesis was the Chi-Square Test of Independence which determines whether there is an association between categorical variables (Gender and Education Loan taken or not), but I used the two-sample z-test for the alternate hypothesis (H1) that the proportion of boys taking education loan is higher than proportion of girls. With the given data in the table, I decided that my hypothesis was more suitable.

Please tell me if there is a standard way to determine which hypothesis is suitable?